# QTimer::singleShot only calling lambda when interval is 0

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

Note: My original post had an important omission: I left out that I had already instantiated the main `QApplication` instance at the beginning of main. Creating two `QApplication` instances is what caused the problem. Using the same `QApplication` instance instead of creating two fixed the issue.

My intention is to run a `QApplication` before the main application to iterate the available Bluetooth devices, to find a specific one. If the specific one is not found in a certain time limit, the `QApplication` is terminated. The first stored lambda (`startDiscovery`) is called as soon as `QApplication::exec()` is called, but the second stored lambda (`cancelDiscovery`) is never called! The relevant section is below:

```
#include <QtBluetooth/QBluetoothDeviceInfo>
#include <QtBluetooth/QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QtBluetooth/QBluetoothLocalDevice>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QString>
#include <QApplication>

#include <memory>
#define TARGET_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_NAME "MyBluetoothDevice"  
#define BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT 5000 //5 second timeout

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    std::shared_ptr<QApplication> mainApplication{std::make_shared<QApplication>(argc, argv)};
    //Error checking for no adapters and powered off devices 
    //omitted for sake of brevity
    auto bluetoothAdapters = QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices();
    std::shared_ptr<QBluetoothLocalDevice> localDevice{std::make_shared<QBluetoothLocalDevice>(bluetoothAdapters.at(0).address())};

    std::shared_ptr<QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent> discoveryAgent{std::make_shared<QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>(localDevice.get())};
    std::shared_ptr<QBluetoothDeviceInfo> targetDeviceInfo{nullptr};

    std::shared_ptr<QApplication> findBluetooth{std::make_shared<QApplication>(argc, argv)};
    auto setTargetDeviceInfo = [=](QBluetoothDeviceInfo info) {
        if (info.name() == TARGET_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_NAME) {
            targetDeviceInfo = std::make_shared<QBluetoothDeviceInfo>(info);
            discoveryAgent->stop();
            findBluetooth->exit(0);
        }
    };

    auto cancelDiscovery = [=]() {
        discoveryAgent->stop();
        findBluetooth->exit(1);
    };

    auto startDiscovery = [=]() {
        discoveryAgent->start();
    };

    QObject::connect(discoveryAgent.get(), &QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::deviceDiscovered, setTargetDeviceInfo);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, startDiscovery); //startDiscovery get called fine
    QTimer::singleShot(BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT, cancelDiscovery); //cancelDiscovery never gets called!

    findBluetooth->exec();

    //Now check if targetDeviceInfo is nullptr and run the real application etc...
    mainApplication->exec();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original post had an important omission: I left out that I had already instantiated the main QApplication instance at the beginning of main. Creating two QApplication instances is what caused the problem. Using the same QApplication instance instead of creating two fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: `discoveryAgent->start();` is basically blocking your main thread. That is why, event which gets posted by  `QTimer::singleShot(BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT, cancelDiscovery);` never gets processed - application executing `discoveryAgent->start()` and have not opportunity to look into event loop.

Comment: I was typing same answer. For me it shows such behavior when Bluetooth feature is not ready on PC or device where the code is running. It makes sense to move that to worker thread.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, If I comment out the call to discoveryAgent->start() (or remove the first singleShot), cancelDiscovery still never gets called.

Comment: How do you know? I can not reproduce.

Comment: I figured out my issue. In my actual application, I had already created the main QApplication instance at the beginning of main(), which caused the second to not work as intended.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my main post to reflect that. Sorry about that, and thanks for your time.